# Show specific set of fields

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm trying to show a specific set of fields, extracted from SQL into my crystal report.

```
SqlConnection cnn;
string connectionString = null;
string sql = null;

connectionString = "Data Source=RHYME-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Caproj;Integrated Security=True;";
cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
cnn.Open();
sql = "select DriverID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, ContactNo, EmergencyNumber, Address, Documents, Status, ContactPerson, BirthDate, YearsOfExperience from [Driver Table]";
SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dscmd.Fill(ds, "[Driver Table]");
MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[6].Rows.Count.ToString());
cnn.Close();

DriverReport rpt = new DriverReport();
rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[6]);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

I get an error in the line `"MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[6].Rows.Count.ToString());"` which says,

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot find table 6.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have only one table in your dataset, So you want to change 6 to 0 in

```
MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString());
```

I think this will solve your problem.